# Trying to set the background of android actionbar version 2.1 or so (API 7) and up

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

Alright so I've followed [android tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html) to try and style my action bar and it doesn't seem to work

**themes.xml**

```
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style 
        name="CustomActionBarTheme"
        parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style 
        name="MyActionBar"
        parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**manifest.xml**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" >
```

...

I made sure i have actionbar_background.png(which is an square image with a color basically) in the correct folders. however. when i run the up i still see the old action bar like nothing changed.

Comment: Not cache, I've just tried running it on a different device and a virtual device both showed the old bar.

Comment: this was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15339150/androidactionbarstyle-requires-api-level-11

Comment: Thanks this was the solution